# Why will this program not work in the shell, but work in my IDE?

Tags: python, random, python-3.x, dice

Im having a problem with a dice roller program (text for now but eventually graphical). It **will not** work in anything except for the IDE I use, Wing IDE 101 4.1. The error i get flashes too fast for me to read, but i will try to take a screenshot of it. (I will edit this post if i get a screenshot.)

Here is the program:

```
import random


#variables

available_dice = "D20"
main_pgm_start = False

#definitions of functions

def diePick():
    print("Pick a die. Your choices are: ", available_dice)
    print("")
    which_dice = input("")

    if which_dice == "D20" or which_dice == "d20":
        rollD20()    
    else:
        print("Error: Please try again")
        print("")
        diePick()    

def rollD20():
    print("Rolling D20 .... ")
    print("")
    d20_result = random.randrange(1, 20)
    print("You have rolled a ", d20_result)
    print("")
    print("Would you like to roll again?")
    print("")
    y = input("")
    if y == "y" or y == "Y" or y == "yes" or y == "Yes":
        print("")        
        diePick()



def MainProgram():
    print("Benjamin Ward's Random D&D Dice Roller")
    print("")
    x = input("  Press Enter to Continue")
    print("")
    diePick()


MainProgram()
```

Comment: which python version are you using?

Comment: @mata im using python version 3.2, ill add that to the tags

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Are you sure the python interperter you start from the terminal is also python3 and not python2?

Comment: @mata yep. im getting an error message but it goes away too fast for me to read it. as I said tho, i cant get the error in the ide..... so i cant read it

Comment: @PythonInProgress You can redirect the log to the text file with "logging" module if my memory serves.

Comment: @LonelySoul thanks. post that as an answer and ill accept it, it worked. The problem was that my pythonpath didnt exist, it went to a usb that wasnt there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the log to the text file with "logging" module if my memory serves.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think input() does what you expect it to. input reads a line of text, then executes it (as python).

I think what you want is more along the lines of `stdin.readline()`. To use it, you will have to `from sys import stdin` at the top, then replace all occurences of `input` with `sys.readline()`. Note also that this will return a newline at the end, which you have to account for.

Comment: yeah. ik. im using that as a placeholder so i dont have to use getch(), which i was considering. Also, it doesnt execute it. It stores it in the variable

Comment: the OP is using python3, so you're wrong, input just reads a line of text.

Comment: I'm guessing this is Python 3.x, in which case `input` does no evaluation.